# Is there a benefit to using a Loot-A-Rang?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

The [Loot-A-Rang](http://www.wowhead.com/item=60854) is an item that allows you to "loot a nearby corpse." However, so does right-clicking the corpse. And since this item requires a target in order to be used, you have to click a corpse anyway.

I decided to make a macro to remove the need to click a target:

```
/targetlastenemy [noexists][nodead]
/use [dead]Loot-A-Rang
```

While this seemed clever, I soon realized that the Loot-A-Rang actually has both a cast time and a cooldown. Since I rarely only kill one enemy at a time, this makes regular looting faster than using this macro.

Is there really any benefit to using the Loot-A-Rang?

Comment: Most obvious answer would be if a corpse was in the air and inaccessible.

Comment: Question will be mostly moot anyway within a month or so since Mists is implementing AOE looting: http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/blog/5449283/World_of_Warcraft_PTR_Patch_504_Notes-24_07_2012

Comment: @Lin This is a good point. Now I have to go test it in the beta to see if it's better or worse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imagine a corpse in aggro-range of other monsters. In this scenario you could use a Loot-A-Rang to loot the corpse without getting aggro.

Another use was already mentioned by Domocus: You can loot otherwise inaccessible corpses.

Answer (score 2):

As of 5.2 this item no longer requires a target.

Additionally, in Mists of Pandaria, Blizzard have added AOE looting, which will largely negate the need for the Loot-a-rang outside of very specific circumstances (like being unable to physically reach the slain mob).

Answer (score 0):

0.1-second cast time, 10-second cooldown...

**No**, I'd say you're better off just not using it unless the corpse(s) is/are glitched.